# How to send an email to everyone in the address book?

Tags: mac, software-recommendation, email

How can I easily send a BCC to everyone in my address book on OS X?

I need to send everyone my new email address.

Answer (score 3):

Easy - use [MailChimp](http://mailchimp.com) or some other bulk mailing service to get around all the reasons (spam) that mail clients (spam) and mail services make this (spam) hard to accomplish.

You also might set a vacation auto-reply on the old address and ensure that people get a timely reminder when they email the old.